# Ckeditor in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

in my template i have:

```
<form>
  <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
    This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
  </textarea>
  <script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', { toolbar : [ ['Bold','Italic','Font','FontSize'] ] });
  </script>
</form>
```

and the result is this:

> localhost/PeopleSymfony/web/app_dev.php/index/config.js?t=G4CD Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>       7391ff2_ckeditor_5.js:85 
>       GET http://localhost/PeopleSymfony/web/app_dev.php/index/lang/es.js?t=G4CD http://localhost/PeopleSymfony/web/app_dev.php/index/skins/moono/

i dont know to how solve.
i did php app/console assets:install to reinstalle assets but have the same error

**why  search es.js in 
//localhost/PeopleSymfony/web/app_dev.php/index/lang/es.js?t=G4CD and no in the bundle ivoryckeditor?**

Comment: So please let us know how you embedded the needed js and css that belongs to the CHKEditor

Comment: What was the PHP error in the server error log?

Comment: did you use the ckeditor type in your formtype.php?

Comment: error log [2016-07-04 15:47:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []